# React Native Mobile SDK

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I have followed the instructions to create a react_native sample app on this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/react_native_intro.htm)

Everything works, but what I am trying to understand is where does the

```
oauth.authenticate()
```

Store the tokens, and how does it then pass the token to the forceClient()

Answer (score 2):

I can understand that this can be a bit confusing as it's not really documented very well. The key concept here is that `forcClient` is an instance of `react.force.net.js`

```
var forceClient = require('./react.force.net.js');
```

When a user authenticates using `oauth.authenticate` - under the hood, it returns a data dictionary comprising of

```
 * Returns a dictionary with:
 *     accessToken
 *     refreshToken
 *     clientId
 *     userId
 *     orgId
 *     loginUrl
 *     instanceUrl
 *     userAgent
 */
```

The `forceClient` reads this data dictionary and it has all the session information as well as target org/ user details available to fire subsequent SOQL operations using the `query()` method

As an example

```
var soql = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10';
        forceClient.query(soql,
                          function(response) {
                              var users = response.records;
                              var data = [];
                              var count = 0;
                              for (var i in users) {
                                  data.push(users[i]["Name"]);
                                  count++;
                          }
```

I hope that answers your question. I'd recommend watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY2vn2bT6XU) video to understand this in further detail.